# GeoServer 2.25 winsetup download

Tags: geoserver, installation, windows

Looks like the winsetup installer is not available yet, though linked to from the blog announcement:
https://geoserver.org/announcements/vulnerability/2024/03/19/geoserver-2-25-0-released.html

https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.25.0/

Was hoping to trial an upgrade over Easter :)